# I want to build a case statement in sql for the average of a value

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a data set of customers, the number of orders placed and the order value. I am trying to bucket the data into 5 segments based on the average order value of the customer.

```sql
select case
         when avg(total_amount) <= 3.5 then
          '<3.5'
         when avg(total_amount) > 3.5 and avg(total_amount) <= 4.5 then
          ' 3.5-4.5'
         when avg(total_amount) > 4.5 and avg(total_amount) <= 6 then
          ' 4.5-6'
         when avg(total_amount) > 6 and avg(total_amount) <= 8 then
          '6-8'
         else
          'over 8'
       end as bucket,
       count(customer_id),
       avg(total_amount),
       avg(order_count)
  from (select customer_account_id,
               sum(spent amount) as total_amount,
               count(order_id) as order_count
          from data_table
         group by customer_account_id)
 group by bucket;
```

I want only 5 rows of output showing the spent and orders placed in each bucket.

Comment: can you share output of your query and describe problem.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan ... different products, but Redshift is based on an old fork from Postgres, so the 2 databases still share quite a lot in terms of syntax.

Comment: `avg` is an aggregate function, it needs to be calculated for some group of rows. You didn't specify the grouping criteria, how the DBMS should calculate an average?

Comment: Currently the error I am getting is : 
SQL Error [42803]: ERROR: aggregates not allowed in GROUP BY clause
I believe this is because I have an avg() function in the case statement. But how do I work around this?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: no, Redhift is not based on Postgres. In only took the Postgres _parser_ but the underlying architect and storage is completely different. Redshift questions shouldn't be tagged with Postgres

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Good to know this, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this (not tested) :

```
WITH list AS
( SELECT customer_account_id as customer_id,
         sum(spent_amount) as total_amount,
         count(order_id) as order_count
    FROM data_table
   GROUP BY customer_account_id
)
SELECT CASE
         when range = numrange (0, 3.5, '[]') then '<3.5'
         when range = numrange (3.5, 4.5, '(]') then '3.5-4.5'
         when range = numrange (4.5, 6.0, '(]') then '4.5-6'
         when range = numrange (6.0, 8.0, '(]') then '6-8'
         else 'over 8'
       END AS bucket,
       count(customer_id),
       avg(total_amount),
       avg(order_count)
  FROM list
 INNER JOIN (VALUES (numrange (0, 3.5, '[]')),(numrange (3.5, 4.5, '(]')),(numrange (4.5, 6.0, '(]')),(numrange (6.0, 8.0, '(]')),(numrange (8.0, NULL, '(]'))) AS range
    ON range @> total_amount
 GROUP BY range
```